# HTML5 FileReader + WebSQL

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

Ist it possible to parse a csv-file with FileReader an write it a WebSql Table?

Answer (score 1):

The FileReader.readAsText() method will give you a string from the file which you can then split() to get the lines and csv cells.  Check out [readAsText()](http://www.javascripture.com/FileReader#readAsText) for more details and try pasting the following in to the interactive example:

```
<script id='csv' type='text/plain'>
apple,1,$1.00
banana,4,$0.20
orange,3,$0.79
</script>
<script>
  // Use a Blob to simulate a File
  var csv = document.getElementById('csv').textContent.trim();
  var file = new Blob([csv]);

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event){
    var reader = event.target;

    var text = reader.result;
    var lines = text.split('\n');

    lines.forEach(function(line) {
      var parts = line.split(',');

      // process the cells in the csv
      console.log(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
    });
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should not be a problem at all :)

Just use `FileReader.readAsText()` to grab the csv file content, and from there it should be a  breeze

Answer (score 0):

With [Screw-FileReader](https://github.com/jimmywarting/Screw-FileReader)

```js
// Use a Blob to simulate a File
let blob = new Blob([
`apple,1,$1.00
banana,4,$0.20
orange,3,$0.79`
])

blob.text().then(text => {
  var lines = text.split('\n')

  for (let line of lines) {
    let parts = line.split(',')

    // process the cells in the csv
    console.log(parts)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jimmywarting/Screw-FileReader/master/index.js"></script>
```